# Casting generics types C#

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to have have an interface, which allow me to keep object of generic type class.
Some code and more explanation below:

```
    public interface IItem { }
public interface IClass1<T> : IEnumerable<T> { }
public class Item1 : IItem { }
public class Item2 : IItem { }
public class Class1<T> : IClass1<T> where T : class, IItem { }
public class Class2<T> : IClass1<T> where T : class, IItem { }
public class Class : UserControl
{
    IClass1<IItem> _item;
    public virtual IClass1<IItem> item
    {
    get
        {
            return _item;
        }
    set
        {
            _item = value;
            //then do something...
        }
    }
    public Class2()
    {
        //few examples what I would like to do
        item = new Class1<Item1>();
        item = new Class1<Item2>();
        item = new Class2<Item1>();
        item = new Class2<Item2>();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Class2 will serve as the basis for inheriting classes and I know only that, the field _item will be keeping object of class implementing some generic interface(interface inherits from IEnumerable so it has to be generic) and i have no idea how I can force the field item to accept object of class implementing this interface,(while their generic type can be Item1, Item2 etc. but their all implements IItem interface)

Comment: What's your actual _question_? What does the code you posted do that is different from what you want it to do? What _specifically_ are you having trouble figuring out?

Comment: This isn't your real code. Your `Class` class has a constructor called `Class2`. Please try to make this code more accurate and, please, rename the classes so it's clearer as to what you're doing. Try naming them like `IFruit` and `Apple`, `Banana`, etc. Then we can be more sure about what's going on. Calling an interface `IClass1` is confusing. Having a class called `Class2` implementing an interface `IClass1` is just trying make our job unnecessarily hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your classes redefined into something more understandable:

```
public interface IFruit { }
public interface ICollectionOfFruit<T> : IEnumerable<T> { }
public class Apple : IFruit { }
public class Banana : IFruit { }
public class BoxOfFruit<T> : ICollectionOfFruit<T> where T : class, IFruit { public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); } IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
public class BagOfFruit<T> : ICollectionOfFruit<T> where T : class, IFruit { public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); } IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
public class Class
{
    ICollectionOfFruit<IFruit> _item;

    public Class()
    {
        //few examples what I would like to do
        _item = new BoxOfFruit<Apple>();
        _item = new BoxOfFruit<Banana>();
        _item = new BagOfFruit<Apple>();
        _item = new BagOfFruit<Banana>();
    }
}
```

What you need to understand is that even if `Apple` inherits (implements) `IFruit` then `ICollectionOfFruit<Apple>` does not inherit from `ICollectionOfFruit<IFruit>`

If `ICollectionOfFruit<T>` inherited `IList<T>` then casting `BoxOfFruit<Apple>` to `ICollectionOfFruit<IFruit>` would allow you to add a `Banana` to the collection. And that would blow up at run-time.

In your case, however, `ICollectionOfFruit<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>` so there is one simple change you can make to make your code work:

```
public interface ICollectionOfFruit<out T> : IEnumerable<T> { }
```

Because of the `out` it means you will never try to put `in` to your collection an `IFruit` and thus it is safe to allow the cast.

However, if your real use case allows `ICollectionOfFruit<T>` to take a `T` as an input to a method then you can't use `out`.